# Azure sql database usages and cost

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are using Azure Elastic pool sql server.

**Is there any way to get usages and cost for individual database instead of elastic pool**?

Comment: This is no SO question, and the answer is just a [Google away](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool). Since you're paying for the pool, costs per database equal the percentage of resources used for each database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this official document:[Monitor an elastic pool and its databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool#monitor-an-elastic-pool-and-its-databases).

**Summary**:

In the Azure portal, you can monitor the utilization of an elastic pool and the databases within that pool. You can also make a set of changes to your elastic pool and submit all changes at the same time. These changes include adding or removing databases, changing your elastic pool settings, or changing your database settings.

To start monitoring your elastic pool, find and open an elastic pool in the portal. You will first see a screen that gives you an overview of the status of your elastic pool. 
This includes:

1. Monitoring charts showing resources usage of the elastic pool
2. Recent alerts and recommendations, if available, for the elastic pool

I think it can helps you. You can get usages and cost for each database on Azure Protal.